# charts flutter examples does not run

Tags: flutter, charts

I tried to run the charts_flutter examples v 0.12.0 with flutter 2.10
flutter pub get produces the following errors:
The current Dart SDK version is 2.16.1.

Because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 depends on yaml ^2.0.0 and test >=1.19.0 <1.19.3 depends on test_api 0.4.6, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 or >=1.19.0 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.4.6.
And because test >=1.18.1 <1.19.0 depends on test_api 0.4.5, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 or >=1.18.1 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.4.5 or 0.4.6.
And because test >=1.18.0 <1.18.1 depends on test_api 0.4.4 and test >=1.17.11 <1.18.0 depends on test_api 0.4.3, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 or >=1.17.11 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6.
And because test >=1.17.10 <1.17.11 depends on test_api 0.4.2 and test >=1.17.6 <1.17.10 depends on test_api 0.4.1, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 or >=1.17.6 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6.
And because test >=1.17.0 <1.17.6 depends on test_api 0.4.0 and test >=1.16.7 <1.17.0 depends on test_api 0.3.0, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 or >=1.16.7 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.3.0 or 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6.
And because test >=1.16.6 <1.16.7 depends on test_api 0.2.20 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.16.6 depends on test_api 0.2.19, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.12 or >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.2.19 or 0.2.20 or 0.3.0 or 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6.
And because test >=1.3.0 <1.16.0-nullsafety depends on yaml ^2.0.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.10 <1.16.1 depends on analyzer >=0.36.0 <0.42.0, test >=1.3.0 <1.16.0-nullsafety or >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.19.3-∞ requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.2.19 or 0.2.20 or 0.3.0 or 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6 or analyzer >=0.36.0 <0.42.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test >=1.19.3 <1.19.4 depends on test_core 0.4.8, test >=1.3.0 <1.19.4 requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.2.19 or 0.2.20 or 0.3.0 or 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6 or analyzer >=0.36.0 <0.42.0 or test_core 0.4.8.
And because test >=1.20.0 depends on test_api 0.4.9 and test >=1.19.4 <1.20.0 depends on test_core 0.4.9, test >=1.3.0 requires yaml ^2.0.0 or test_api 0.2.19 or 0.2.20 or 0.3.0 or 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6 or 0.4.9 or analyzer >=0.36.0 <0.42.0 or test_core 0.4.8 or 0.4.9.
And because test_core >=0.4.5 <0.4.10 depends on analyzer ^2.4.0 which depends on yaml ^3.0.0, if analyzer >=1.0.0 <2.4.0-∞ or >=3.0.0-0 and test >=1.3.0 then test_api 0.2.19 or 0.2.20 or 0.3.0 or 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 or 0.4.2 or 0.4.3 or 0.4.4 or 0.4.5 or 0.4.6 or 0.4.9.
And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.8 and mockito >=5.0.0 <5.0.12 depends on analyzer ^1.0.0, one of flutter_test from sdk or test >=1.3.0 or mockito >=5.0.0 <5.0.12 must be false.
And because mockito >=5.0.8 depends on code_builder ^4.0.0 and build_runner >=0.9.1+1 <2.0.0 depends on code_builder >2.3.0 <4.0.0, one of flutter_test from sdk or test >=1.3.0 or mockito >=5.0.0 or build_runner >=0.9.1+1 <2.0.0 must be false.
And because charts_flutter depends on both mockito ^5.0.0 and build_runner ^1.11.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.3.0.
So, because charts_flutter depends on both flutter_test from sdk and test ^1.3.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because charts_flutter depends on both flutter_test from sdk and test ^1.3.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

How can I fix this?

Comment: Will you please share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: use version 0.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Dart SDK by using commands

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```